# File not found Google Analytics api

Tags: php, google-analytics

I'm trying to use [Google Analytics API](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) with this [tutorial from Google](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-php), but I'm getting an error on this line:

```
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google/autoload.php';
```

It says it can't find the file, which is right. I checked on Git repository, and the file is not there or in any other folder of the repository. How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you installing the library through Composer?

Comment: grab v1-master https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/tree/v1-master

Comment: The documentation has been updated https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-php#install. I don't think this is necessarily a duplicate question of the one asked 11 months ago. This was more of an issue of checking out the correct branch tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks more like an GIT issue. Did you follow step 2 and cloned the GIT repository? ( git clone https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client.git ) Without it, you wont have the files.

Either do a GIT clone, and verify where the files are cloned to, or manually download the files and add them to your project ( https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/releases ).

Once added, double check if the URL to the file is correct.

Comment: Not really a git issue the master branch uses composer now for some reason which does not include this file if you want this file you have to use the v1-master branch